# BeforeSend passed to Backbone's Fetch not allowing events to be triggered

Tags: events, backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone-events

I have a Backbone collection. I'm using `fetch` to lazy load Facebook posts into a model on initialization.

https://gist.github.com/2271437

```
exports.Collection = class Posts extends Backbone.Collection
  initialize: (models, options) =>
    @id = options.id
    @activeDetails = false
    @on "loadDetails", @loadDetails
    @on "detailsLoaded", @logger
    debug "initialized posts"
    @fetch
      beforeSend: () =>
        console.log "about to fetch..."
        @trigger "postsLoading"
      success: (collection, response) => 
        debug "successfully loaded ajax"
        @trigger "postsLoaded"
      error: (collection, response) => @trigger "postsLoadingError"
```

For some strange reason, when I try to trigger events using the `beforeSend` handler, events don't trigger. I can call any functions, but if any functions try to use `@trigger "eventName"`, the event never fires in a way which I've been able to observe. In the example above, the console.log function works just fine, but the trigger fails.

Any ideas? The success and error handlers work splendidly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `fetch` inside your `initialize` method so nothing will have a chance to bind to that collection before the events are triggered. The `initialize` method is called while an instance of your collection is being created and that means that you're calling `fetch` before the constructor returns, but you need an instance of the collection before you can bind to its events.

Consider something that looks more like this:

```
class Posts extends Backbone.Collection
  do_things: ->
    @fetch
      beforeSend: () =>
        console.log "about to fetch..."
        @trigger "postsLoading"
      success: (collection, response) => 
        debug "successfully loaded ajax"
        @trigger "postsLoaded"
      error: (collection, response) => @trigger "postsLoadingError"
```

Then if you do this:

```
p = new Posts
p.on('postsLoading', -> console.log('loading'))     
p.do_things()
```

you will see that your `postsLoading` event is indeed triggered.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/PDeFg/

The moral of the story is simple:

> Don't call `fetch` inside your constructor if you care about event listeners.

Comment: I LOVE YOU.

Could I setTimeout another function in the object to wait a tick before fetching and still have the benefits of fetching when the object is initialized?

Comment: @RandallB: The old `setTimeout(..., 0)` trick inside `initialize` should work as long as the caller binds their event handlers right after instantiating the collection (and you'd probably want to document this behavior).